# How to configure SOAP endpoint on my PC

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I'm  new at using SoapUI, I'd like to know if my machine supports SOAP and in case yes, what I can use as an endpoint for my newly created SoapUI project.

My machine is a Windows-10, and on top of that I have installed Cygwin (enabling some UNIX features).

Does somebody know how I can retrieve a possible value for an endpoint for my SoapUI project?

Oops, from the comment I have the impression that my question is badly formulated: on my PC I have a server application, of which I don't know if it supports SOAP (I know it supports HTTP because I'm using `localhost` in a browser to access it).
However when I use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as an endpoint in my SoapUI project, nothing happens (I see no response and the request log stays empty), hence my question.

Comment: If your machine can make a TCP/IP connection it supports SOAP. So yes it does. You r question makes no sense at all. SOAP UI is used to test and mock services it is by no means used to create a service. Its a testing framework. You need to develop your SOAP service in a language like Java /C# etc.

Comment: @Namphibian: I've reformulated my question for clarity reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per default, mostly no application will act as a SOAP prodiver, as it is much more complicated as REST/http for example.

If your application has the capability of a SOAP provider, it is usually SOAP over HTTP. But you need to know the correct endpoint url address.
Not only 127.0.0.1
Usually there is a servicename in the url (and you can also try to show wsdl with ?wsdl), like http://127.0.0.1/myapplication/myservice?wsdl

when setting up a new soapui project, you also have to provide the wsdl location 
(http://127.0.0.1/myapplication/myservice?wsdl)

Regards, rka